# How to implement HTTP POST method in web proxy through Java

Tags: java, http, network-programming, http-post, http-proxy

I am trying to make a web proxy for HTTP communication between server and client. The GET method is working fine but I am POST method part is not working. I am sure I have missed out something. I want to know what have I missed or not implemented.

```
// request from client is handle from here
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            try {

                StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(inputLine);
                tok.nextToken();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                break;
            }

            if (cnt == 0) {
                 System.out.println("inputLine "+inputLine);
                String[] tokens = inputLine.split(" ");
                urlToCall = tokens[1];
                //hum inputline sy URL nikaal rahay hai
                if(tokens[0]=="POST")
                {
                    f=1;
                }

                System.out.println("Request for : " + urlToCall);
            }

            cnt++;
        }

        BufferedReader rd = null;
        try {
            //yaha sy hum ab server ko request send karay gy
            URL url = new URL(urlToCall);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            conn.setDoOutput(false);

            // now we will get the response from the server

            if (f == 1) {
                huc.setDoOutput(true);
                huc.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                huc.setRequestMethod("POST");
                huc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                huc.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            }

            InputStream is = null;
            if (conn.getContentLength() > 0)
            {
                try {
                    is = conn.getInputStream();
                    rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.out.println(
                            "********* IO EXCEPTION **********: " + ioe);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP POST method for web proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855829/http-post-method-for-web-proxy)

Comment: It is different from that Question

Comment: Your question title is the same ! Wait for the answer rather than just posting same question again. If you need, you can edit the same post with some modifications and repost it !

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting on the post?  And what is a sample GET request that is being passed into your code?

When I use a simple GET request, the code fails because the urlToCall does not have the host or protocol.  The below code worked for me, but I would highly suggest you change your code to not hide the exceptions that are being thrown because they will have important information about what is going wrong with your code.

```
if (cnt == 1) {
            System.out.println("host: " + inputLine);
            String[] tokens = inputLine.split(" ");
            urlToCall = "HTTP://" + tokens[1] + urlToCall;
        }
```

Comment: I am not receiving any error. The problem I am facing is that my code is not able to deal with POST method. The GET method is working perfectly fine.